# Converting existing iPhone project to universal in MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm looking to figure out how to convert a working application from iPhone only to universal in MonoTouch.  It appears there's a tool in xCode that does this.  Is this tool relevant for monotouch?  Or is there one for MT that does what the xCode one does?

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 3):

in the info.plist change the devices to Universal(that works for me)
and like in the universal example made by Xcode and MonoDevelop you will need to implement the code that handles each iDevice

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
{
}else{
}
```

after you run your app change the device in simulator to iPad and you will see the change